# How to use html-pdf with jsZip

Tags: javascript, node.js, jszip, html-pdf

I generate some html text and then translate it to pdf using html-pdf package. Then I wanna put it into archive created by jsZip. In every example they use `.toStream((err, stream) => stream.pipe(res))` but I cant find how to put it into archive.

I have tried `zip.file('newPDF.pdf', pdf.create(html).toStream())` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
const createPDF = (html) => new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
    pdf.create(html).toStream((err, stream) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else resolve(stream);
    });
}));

const PDF = await createPDF(html);
zip.file('newPDF.pdf', PDF);
```